# Performance: Query to external MYSQL or HTTP post to a PHP file on the server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, performance, external

I'm developing an Android application that will need to query to an external MYSQL database. To do that, which is the best way to get the best *performance* and to trying to avoid overcharging of database:

- Do a query directly to MYSQL Database, or
- Do a HTTP POST to a PHP file and do a local query to MYSQL Database (note that using this way I can control the input and play with it before doing the query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution for you to connect your application to MySQL database by using JSON and PHP. You can do scripting in PHP page before executing query. Visit this page,

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

*Do a query directly to MYSQL Database* is **better**. Let mySql to manage him self, he should be able synchronize what ever is needed and what ever is not.